# Accumulo - Means of checking BatchWriter progress

Tags: java, collections, mutation, accumulo

Scenario is that I have several threads that ultimately add collections of mutations to specific BatchWriters. I don't want my program to close before all of the mutations are pushed to the Cluster. Is there a way to check the BatchWriter progress or does the BatchWriter stall until it gets through its collection of mutations or am I missing something altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you call close() on your BatchWriters after adding all mutations, you'll be fine. The close() method will block on the client side.